# How to avoid the page loading every row from the database when filters are not applied?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I created a Razor Page where user can adjust filters to get matching rows from the database. However I don't want that the page displays every row if there are no filters applied. This happens every time the page is initially loaded or when the filters are turned off. This is happening in the .cs file

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
  var query = from c in _context.Pokedex select c;

  if (GrassSwitch == true)
  {
    query = query.Where(p => p.type1 == "grass" || p.type2 == "grass");
  }
  if (FireSwitch == true)
  {
    query = query.Where(p => p.type1 == "fire" || p.type2 == "fire");
  }

  //...more filters...

  Pokedex = await query.ToListAsync();
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And this in the .cshtml

```
//filter bar
<input class="type-checkbox" type="checkbox" asp-for="GrassSwitch" value="true" onchange="this.form.submit();" />

//...more filters...

//display rows from the database
@foreach (var item in Model.Pokedex)
{
  <div>
    @item.name
  </div>
  <div>
    @item.type1
  </div>
}
```

I tried asking ChatGPT and it insisted on having all the filtering logic inside OnPost() method. However, I have it inside OnGet() because that's what Codecademy taught me and the page is working fine other than the problem I'm now trying to solve. I already tried moving the code from OnGet() to OnPost() but run into number of issues of page not loading. So if this is the way to do it, I'll have to look at it more. But if there's another solution where the filter logic can stay inside OnGet(), I'd like to hear about that, thank you!

Edit: Pagination is an option, but the most ideal way here would be to just prevent the website loading any rows when filters are not applied. There are about 1000 rows in the database so when filters are applied there are a couple of hundred rows displayed at maximum, so it's okay to dispaly them without pagination. My aim is just to reduce data traffic by preventing unnecessary loading of all the rows every time the page is loaded.

Edit 2: Using a default filter that would always return 0 rows such as `query = query.Where(p => p.type1 == "xyzab");` is a good idea. However I ended up creating an if-statement in the OnGet() method that checks if any of the filters is active. Because there are a lot of filters, the if-statement looks messy but it does its job.

Comment: You haven't described what behavior you want in the case when no filters are applied. Maybe consider pagination or providing some default filter.

Comment: Pagination is the most common way to avoid loading an entire table: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/328/simple-paging-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages

Comment: A default filter would solve the problem. If no other filters are set, then use a default that can't possibly exist in your data, such as `query = query.Where(p => p.type1 == "xyzab");`. This would return zero rows, which solves your issue nicely.